# Unable to test SagePay v4.0 integration

Tags: opayo

The following request does not result in 3DAUTH response (3D secure is enabled):
POST https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspdirect-register.vsp

```
VPSProtocol=4.00&Vendor=adventureworks&Currency=GBP&TxType=AUTHENTICATE&VendorTxCode=689359&Amount=158.00&Description=1%20x%20Membership;%20&Basket=1:Membership:1:131.67:26.33:158.00:158.00&CardHolder=Test%20Visa&CardNumber=4929000000006&ExpiryDate=0834&CV2=123&CardType=VISA&BillingFirstnames=Test&BillingSurname=TEst&BillingAddress1=88&BillingCity=london&BillingPostCode=412&BillingCountry=GB&DeliveryFirstnames=Test&DeliverySurname=Test&DeliveryAddress1=88&DeliveryCity=london&DeliveryPostCode=412&DeliveryCountry=GB&ClientIPAddress=10.13.10.191&BrowserJavascriptEnabled=1&BrowserJavaEnabled=1&BrowserColorDepth=24&BrowserScreenHeight=600&BrowserScreenWidth=800&BrowserTZ=0&BrowserAcceptHeader=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3&BrowserLanguage=en-GB&BrowserUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/76.0.3809.132%20Safari/537.36&ThreeDSNotificationURL=https://someurl.co.uk/join/callback3DSecure.asp&ChallengeWindowSize=02&CustomerEmail=test@test.com&contains=function(n)%20%7B%0D%0Afor%20(var%20i%20=%200;%20i%20%3C%20this.length;%20i++)%20if%20(this%5Bi%5D%20==%20n)%20return(true);%0D%0Areturn(false);%0D%0A%7D
```

Tried with `BrowserJavascriptEnabled='0'`, same response.
What am I doing wrong?

I get a successful transaction created is SagePay with 3D response OK
[image]

Comment: What is the response you get? Do you get the payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CHALLENGE as Cardholder Name and you get the challenge window.

Use STATUS201DS to test the fall back to 3DSv1.

**EDIT:**

Documentation: [DIRECT_Integration_and_Protocol_4_Guidelines.pdf](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/library/document/directintegrationandprotocol4guidelinespdf)

Comment: is this in any official document from SagePay? No mention here: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/test-card-details-for-your-test-transactions

Comment: @Pencho Ilchev I have added the link to my answer